# python combing three lists to one in specific format

Tags: python, list

I have three lists which I want to make into one list (including all possible combinations 4 for each country abbreviation ) the string they should be is as the following

```
query = f'c_code={country}&min_age={age[0]}&max_age={age[1]}&gender={gender}'
```

i.e each country will have 4 strings, I made the following three for loops to do it but I believe this isn't very pythonic.

```
country_abb=['ID', 'IR', 'IQ', 'IE', 'IM', 'IL', 'IT', 'CI', 'JM', 'JP', 'JE', 'JO', 'KI', 'KW', 'KG', 'LA', 'LV', 'LB', 'LS', 'LR', 'LY', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'MO', 'MK', 'MG', 'MW', 'MY', 'MV', 'ML', 'MT', 'MH', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MU', 'YT', 'MX', 'FM', 'MD', 'MC', 'MN', 'ME', 'MS', 'NA', 'NP', 'NL', 'NC', 'NZ', 'NI', 'NE', 'NG', 'MP', 'NO', 'OM', 'PK', 'PW']
genders = ['male','female']
ages_range = [[16,25],[26,50]]
all_queries = []
for country in country_abb:
    for gender in genders:
        for age in ages_range:
            query = f'c_code={country}&min_age={age[0]}&max_age={age[1]}&gender={gender}'
            all_queries.append(query)
```

Comment: @roganjosh hypen in ages_range[1]

Comment: @roganjosh Fixed I i had - isntead of comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `product` from `itertools`. I don't know if it is that more pythonic, but it is a bit shorter and I find it more readable, but I guess you milage may vary:

```
from itertools import product

country_abb=['ID', 'IR', 'IQ', 'IE', 'IM', 'IL', 'IT', 'CI', 'JM', 'JP', 'JE', 'JO', 'KI', 'KW', 'KG', 'LA', 'LV', 'LB', 'LS', 'LR', 'LY', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'MO', 'MK', 'MG', 'MW', 'MY', 'MV', 'ML', 'MT', 'MH', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MU', 'YT', 'MX', 'FM', 'MD', 'MC', 'MN', 'ME', 'MS', 'NA', 'NP', 'NL', 'NC', 'NZ', 'NI', 'NE', 'NG', 'MP', 'NO', 'OM', 'PK', 'PW']
genders = ['male','female']
ages_range = [[16,25],[26,50]]
all_queries = []

for country, gender, age in product(country_abb, genders, ages_range):
    query = f'c_code={country}&min_age={age[0]}&max_age={age[1]}&gender={gender}'
    all_queries.append(query)
```

`product` creates a list of list where each elements of the orignal lists are combined, quite similiar to a nested for loops in the original post. You can read more about it in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). (Thanks, @roganjosh, for suggesting adding the link.)

Comment: what does product exactly do?

Comment: It creates a list of list where each elements of the orignal lists are combined, quite similiar to a nested `for` loops in the original post.

Comment: will it give all combinations if I add more age_ranges e.g `ages_range = [[16,25],[26,50],[0,15],[51,80]]` ?

Comment: Yes, just as with the nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use `list comprehension`:

```
country_abb=['ID', 'IR', 'IQ', 'IE', 'IM', 'IL', 'IT', 'CI', 'JM', 'JP', 'JE', 'JO', 'KI', 'KW', 'KG', 'LA', 'LV', 'LB', 'LS', 'LR', 'LY', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'MO', 'MK', 'MG', 'MW', 'MY', 'MV', 'ML', 'MT', 'MH', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MU', 'YT', 'MX', 'FM', 'MD', 'MC', 'MN', 'ME', 'MS', 'NA', 'NP', 'NL', 'NC', 'NZ', 'NI', 'NE', 'NG', 'MP', 'NO', 'OM', 'PK', 'PW']
genders = ['male','female']
ages_range = [[16,25],[26,50]]

all_queries = [
    f"c_code={country}&min_age={age[0]}&max_age={age[1]}&gender={gender}"
    for age in ages_range
    for gender in genders
    for country in country_abb
]
```

Comment: it is good to know that it can be done in one list comprehension, but it is basically the same as my code

Comment: @hadesfv yeah, looks better than nested loop.